# How to get background worker thread id

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I would like to identify my background worker thread id.

When I call `RunWorkerAsync()` method it creates a working thread. Naturally, I can get a list with all threads from `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads` method but this list has lots of threads ids and I don't know how to identify my worker thread id.

It's possible that when I call `RunWorkerAsync()` method immediately get this thread id?

Like this

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can do that like this

```
int threadId = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
```

If you what the current process id where all your threads lives.

```
int processId = System.Diagnostics.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
```